# What type of coupled PDE is this?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I have a system of two coupled PDEs and I'm trying to understand what is going on:

$$
\frac{\partial u(x,t)}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial w(x,t)}{\partial x} + u(x,t)w(x,t)\\
\frac{\partial w(x,t)}{\partial t} =  a(x)w(x,t) + b(x)u(x,t) + c(x)
$$

There's a coupling between the $\frac{\partial u(x,t)}{\partial t}$ and $\frac{\partial w(x,t)}{\partial x}$, is there a way to decompose this relationship? I'm free to choose my boundary conditions if need be.

Comment: I assume, that there is a comma between $w(t,x)$  and  $\partial_t w$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\frac{\partial u(x,t)}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial w(x,t)}{\partial x} + u(x,t)w(x,t)\\
\frac{\partial w(x,t)}{\partial t} =  a(x)w(x,t) + b(x)u(x,t) + c(x)
$$
One can separate the functions $u(x,t)$ and $w(x,t)$ :
$$u(x,t)=-\frac{1}{b(x)}\frac{\partial w(x,t)}{\partial t} +  \frac{a(x)}{b(x)}w(x,t) +  \frac{c(x)}{b(x)}$$
$$\boxed{-\frac{1}{b(x)}\frac{\partial^2 w(x,t)}{\partial t^2} +  \frac{a(x)}{b(x)}\frac{\partial w(x,t)}{\partial t}   = \frac{\partial w(x,t)}{\partial x} + \left(-\frac{1}{b(x)}\frac{\partial w(x,t)}{\partial t} +  \frac{a(x)}{b(x)}w(x,t) +  \frac{c(x)}{b(x)} \right)w(x,t)}$$
In this PDE there is only the function $w(x,t)$.
This is a second order nonlinear PDE. One cannot expect an easy solving in general.

Better rely on numerical methods.

An alternative way leads to the same conclusion :

Considering the equation $\frac{\partial w(x,t)}{\partial t} =  a(x)w(x,t) + b(x)u(x,t) + c(x)$ which is an ODE  (since where is only one differential wrt $t$). Solving it for $w(x,t)$ leads to
$$w(x,t)=e^{a(x)t}\left(\int e^{-a(x)t}\big(b(x)u(x,t)+c(x)\big)dt+F(x)\right)$$
$F(x)$ is an arbitrary function.

One put it into $\frac{\partial u(x,t)}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial w(x,t)}{\partial x} + u(x,t)w(x,t)$ . This leads to a first order nonlinear integro-differential equation where $u(x,t)$ is the only unknown. Again one cannot expect an easy solving in general.

Note: Without boundary and without initial condition one cannot go further. Possibly simplification might appear in particular case.